# Issue with JQuery .ajax() function

Tags: jquery, html

I've been problem solving this for the past few hours and frustratingly can't find a solution. I'm trying to submit a form using the JQuery .ajax() function but it's not submitting, heres the code, any suggestions would be much appreciated:

#### JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var livelistURL = "/scripts/livelist.php?guestlist=<?php echo $_GET['guestlist']; ?>";
    var names = '';
    var dot = '.';
    
    $("#livelist").load(livelistURL);
    $("input#name").select().focus();

    $("#addname").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        
        $("input#name").blur();
        $('#working').show();
        $('#event-box').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);  
        
        var guestlist = '<?php echo $_GET['guestlist']; ?>';
        var name = $('input#name');
        var by = '<?php echo $email; ?>';
        
        var data = 'name=' + name.val() + '&guestlist=' + guestlist.val() + '&by=' + by.val();  
    
        $("input#name").blur();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/scripts/addname.php",
            type: "post",
            data: data,
            success: function(){
                var value = $("input#name").val().toUpperCase();;
                $("span.success").text(value);
                
                if (names == '') {
                    names = value;
                }
                else {
                    names = ' ' + value + ', ' + names;
                    $("span#dot").text(dot);
                }
                
                $("span#name1").text(names);
                $('#working').fadeOut('fast');
                $('#success').fadeIn('fast');
                $('#added-names').fadeIn('fast');
                $('#success').delay('600').fadeOut('fast');
                $('#event-box').delay('600').fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
            },
            error: function(){
                $('#working').fadeOut('fast');
                $('#error').fadeIn('fast');
                $('#error').delay('600').fadeOut('fast');
            },
            complete: function(){
                $("input#name").val('');
                $("input#name").select().focus();
            }
        });
    });
}); // end
```

#### Form HTML:

```
<form id="addname">
            <input id="name" name="name" class="tagcheck" style="z-index: 1000;" minlength="5" maxlength="60" placeholder="Add Name" />
        </form>
```

Comment: If you use your browser debugger, does it perform the post, or does the console report a javascript error before that point?

Comment: It reports the error before the post: kyK6Jd:37Uncaught TypeError: Object kyK6Jd has no method 'val'
(anonymous function)kyK6Jd:37
f.event.dispatchjquery.min.js:3
f.event.add.h.handle.i

Comment: That would happen if `$('input#name')` is not successfully selecting an element. I would follow Andy's answer below. I humbly ask if you have ever used a browser debugger? If not, now is the time. I personally love the Chrome inspector. You can set a breakpoint in your script and poke around while the whole thing is "paused" and see what's up with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Firebug, and check the console. This helps you debug your Ajax requests - I use it EXTENSIVELY.

Try removing all your other Javascript stuff, strip it down until it works. Also, there may be an error in addname.php

Comment: Debugger is the way to figure this one out!

Comment: Never knew about this tool - thanks for the tip, have debugged using it already, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of problems I see with this line:

```
var data = 'name=' + name.val() + '&guestlist=' + guestlist.val() + '&by=' + by.val();
```

Note that the guestlist and by variables are not jQuery variables. So you cannot use val(), it will cause an error. Taking out the val() from both should fix that issue.

```
var data = 'name=' + name.val() + '&guestlist=' + guestlist + '&by=' + by;
```

I'm assuming your form has a submit button of some kind right? You just didn't include that part of the form HTML?